# Gradle - How to create and get a simply class from GitHub

Tags: java, eclipse, github, gradle

Im to new in Gradle... and to understand it a little more i want to Create a simply Java Class, with a method... for example "public int plus(int a, int b)...", upload it to GitHub, and use that class in a Gradle Project. Im working in eclipse.
I yet read some guides to simply get a class from maven, but i dont know how to do that in github, and i dont know what files am i real downloading when i use the maven librarys... i think a good example like the asked for me can put me on the way
I dont know where to start... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create jar files(artifact) and upload it to repository. Then you have group id, artifact name and version. Using these three you can inject dependency into your project with gradle.

Try this one.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

Comment: Thanx, i will read that guide, but i want to do that particullary in GitHub, its no the same, is it?

Comment: Github is just web-based Git or version control repository. You can keep your source code there and manage using Git. For distribution you have to upload to any remote repository like maven central, bintray, jcenter or any other repo.